# Cloudformation: User-data in EC2 as well as in Launch Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

It seems like EC2 User-Data takes preference here and never executes Launch Template User-Data.
if I remove User-Data from EC2 it executes LaunchTemplate User-Data without any problem.
The AMI id being used is of CentOS 7.
How can i achieve to run both User-Data in some order.

I have already played around with cloudformation a lot and looked at forums.

```
{
    "Resources": {
        "BSLaunchTemplate": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate",
            "Properties": {
                "LaunchTemplateName": "BroadSoftLaunchTemplate2",
                "LaunchTemplateData": {
                    "KeyName": "haystackaccess",
                    "ImageId": "ami-014b38e758721be30",
                    "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
                    "SecurityGroupIds":["sg-e0b92fa7"],
                    "UserData": {
                        "Fn::Base64": {
                            "Fn::Join":["", [
                                "#!/bin/bash \n",
                                "yum update -y \n",
                                "yum –y install epel-release \n",
                                "yum -y install python-pip \n",
                                "pip install pystache \n",
                                "pip install argparse \n",
                                "pip install python-daemon \n",
                                "pip install requests \n",
                                "yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.amzn1.noarch.rpm \n",        
                                "echo UD_OF_LT_1 >> /var/log/user-data.log \n",
                                "echo UD_OF_LT_2 >> /var/log/user-data.log \n",
                                "echo UD_OF_Lt_3 >> /var/log/user-data.log \n"
                            ]
                        ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "primaryec2": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "LaunchTemplate": {
                    "LaunchTemplateId":{"Ref":"BSLaunchTemplate"},
                    "Version":"1",
                },
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "Network Server"
                    }],
                "UserData":{
                        "Fn::Base64": {
                            "Fn::Join": ["",[
                                "#!/bin/bash \n",
                                "echo UD_OF_EC2_1 >> /var/log/user-data.log \n",
                                "echo UD_OF_EC2_2 >> /var/log/user-data.log \n",
                                "echo UD_OF_EC2_3 >> /var/log/user-data.log \n"
                            ]
                        ]
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of the primary ec2 instance? I guess you need to run the extra commands on the primary. I mean you could just duplicate the commands - putting them into external bash files might make life a bit easier there. Or create an AMI with the commands you used in the launch template and then use your custom AMI in the primary instance. You might be able to do something with conditionals too, but I think you'd have to be a bit more creative with that since I don't think you can use them directly in the user data itself.

Tim